# Is there a name for the trope of a friend who gradually turns into an enemy as a war develops?

Tags: trope

There are some war/dystopian movies when, as some sort of violent regimen grows, former friends or acquaintances - who usually have opposing viewpoints to the protagonist, to some degree - end up becoming part of the regiment, usually as officials or authority figures of some sort.

Some examples:

- "The Pianist" - a friend of Szpilman becomes a Ghetto Police Officer;
- "Dr. Zhivago" - Pasha Antipov becomes Strelnikov;

The trope poses a symbolic question, IMO, as to the extent to which political divergences between you and some person you know are potentially dangerous if the power balance is disturbed.

Comment: So, yeah, I guess such a trope exists. Now what is the actual question you're asking here?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson "(How do you call the) trope for a friend who gradually turns into an enemy as a war develops?"

Comment: Please ask your question in the form of a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Face Heel Turn, as coined in wrestling for a face character, the good guy, to turn into a heel, a bad guy. Also http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BigBadSlippage or We Used to Be Friends if it's someone close to the main character. Any number of sub tropes to those really.

Comment: Nice answer! The best sub-trope, according to my intended description, is [Well-Intentioned Extremist](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WellIntentionedExtremist).